# Adding Facebook Like box and JS SDK to Plone

Tags: facebook, plone

The current Facebook best practice recommends adding FB JS SDK separately to the page `<body>` and then having a Facebook Like Box rendered via JS insteadf of `<iframe>`:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

- Are there currently any Plone add-ons for adding Facebook Like box or other Facebook functionality to Plone following these best practices?
- If not what would be the best way to accomplish the functionality - static text portlet is not probably a way to go due to safe HTML transformations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that http://plone.org/products/simplesocial does all or most of what you want.  Contributions welcome!

Answer (score 0):

We haven't implemented this yet (because we haven't needed it) but it could be easily included in [collective.facebook.portlets](https://github.com/collective/collective.facebook.portlets).

Answer (score 0):

You could paste the snippet from Facebook into a [collective.portlet.tal](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.portlet.tal) portlet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using collective.portlet.embed to paste HTML embed snippet in Plone (like twitter widget or facebook likebox) with extra portlet manager (like collective.masonry)